# Search function ignores query in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, search

I'm trying to make this search function work, but apparently it ignores the query I have and instead lists all the products from the assortment.

This is from the Search function.

```
public function render()
{
    if($this->sorting=="date")
    {
        $products=Product::where('name','like','%'.$this->search.'%')->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->paginate($this->pagesize);
    }
    else if($this->sorting=="price")
    {
        $products=Product::where('name','like','%'.$this->search.'%')->orderBy('regular_price','ASC')->paginate($this->pagesize);
    }
    else if($this->sorting=="price-desc")
    {
        $products=Product::where('name','like','%'.$this->search.'%')->orderBy('regular_price','DESC')->paginate($this->pagesize);
    }
    else 
    {

        $products=Product::where('name','LIKE','%'.$this->search.'%')->paginate($this->pagesize); // daca e default merge pe asta
    }

    $categories=Category::all();


    return view('livewire.header-search-component',['products'=>$products,'categories'=>$categories])->layout('layouts.base');
}
```

Search front-end looks like this:

```
<div class="search-model">
    <div class="h-100 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <div class="search-close-switch">+</div>
        <form action="{{ route('product.search') }}" class="search-model-form">
            <input type="text" name='search' id="search-input" value="{{$search}}" placeholder="Search products here.....">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you dd() the $this->search to discard that it's not empty?

Comment: change `where('name','like','%'.$this->search.'%')` to `where('name','like',"'%".$this->search."%'")`. The pattern given to the like statement has to be a string; inside single quotes

Comment: change where('name','like','%'.$this->search.'%') to where('name','like',"'%".$this->search."%'"). The pattern given to the like statement has to be a string; inside single quotes

This solved it! Thank you kindly!

Comment: Hey! I've got another issue now. It doesn't seem to pull the searched product now!
I checked if the $search variable is correct and if it transmits it to the blade page and it does. It seems to be something in the query again! 

Whatever I search it won't return anything, basically it won't pull out the product from the database. 

Here's how it looks like now

Comment: $products=Product::where('name','like',"'%".$this->search."%'")->paginate($this->pagesize);
I can't see anything wrong with it. If something stands out for you please point it out